# In which case Apache Httpd writes "X" when connection is closed? Is it client side or server side?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, connection

Standing to official Apache [mod_log_config docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html) 
I see it writes "X" when "Connection aborted before the response completed".

```
    Connection status when response is completed:
    X = Connection aborted before the response completed.
    + = Connection may be kept alive after the response is sent.
    - = Connection will be closed after the response is sent.
```

What does this mean? 
Is there a way I can simulate this behaviour?

Thank you

Comment: Anyone that knows when it writes X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this often.

It may happen when for example Apache is processing the reply and client aborts the connection before the reply has been sent.

Where I see it very often is when I have balancers on top my Apache HTTPD servers, client has made a POST, backend server is taking a while to reply, timeout for F5/Firewall kicks in, **connection is silently dropped**, when Apache HTTPD has the answer and it is trying to send it back, there is nobody there.